# XML file as input to LoadXml returns xml exception c#

Tags: c#, xml

In my unit testing project, I have merged all my xml files into single xml file and need to send to webservice to seperate it into modules.

So, I have used the below code in my webservice,

```
//xmlString is my xml file content

try
{
    XElement XmlDocument = new XElement("XMLDocument");
    XmlDocument testDoc = new XmlDocument();
    testDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
    XmlDocument = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(testDoc));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string returnString = ex.StackTrace.ToString();

    returnString += "XML breaks the code";

    return returnString;
}
```

**EDIT: While running this in finalbuilder, I am getting below exception**

> **Exception Message:    at ModuleSeparator.GetDetails(String xmlString) System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.**
>
> Results
>       Return value of 'ModuleSeparator' :    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>          at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
>          at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
>          at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
>          at ModuleSeparator.GetDetails(String xmlString)XML breaks the code
>       Setting variable 'ModuleWiseTestCaseResults' to value '   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>          at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
>          at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
>          at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
>          at ModuleSeparator.GetDetails(String xmlString)XML breaks the code'.

**My XML will look like,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test-results name="Merged results" total="418" errors="0" failures="0" not-run="0" inconclusive="128" ignored="0" skipped="7" invalid="0" date="2016-03-08" time="10:47:33">
    <test-suite type="Test Project" name="" executed="True" result="Skipped" success="True" time="311.143731" asserts="0">
        <results></results>
    </test-suite>
</test-results>
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with `Xml`, why can't you try simple load like `var doc = XElement.Parse(xmlString);` ?

Comment: Sorry, Please see the edit. I have included xml file.

Comment: Why are you using a mixture of LINQ to XML and the old XmlDocument API? I would strongly recommend using just LINQ to XML if you possibly can.

Comment: That code works fine with that document. Please show a [mcve]. My guess is that your string doesn't *actually* contain that document, but it's hard to tell given that you've included a stack trace but not the *message* of the exception, and we can't reproduce it with what you've shown us.

Comment: I have added exception message. Please see the Edit message.

Comment: @Hari prasad: I have tried your solution. I am getting the same exception. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. at

Comment: Jon Skeet is right. Don't mix XElement with XmlDocument. Use XDocument instead!